# Symfony 3 with Sonata Dynamically form update. Based on Chosen Value from Select Field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, sonata

What I'm trying to make. I have Posts, Categories and Properties. I can create Categories with a realtionship to many Properties on my Post Admin Page. In my Posts I can chose one Category. And when I chose the Category ( Select Field ), after this I will display the chosen Properties as ( Input Fields ).

Dropdown and Textfield on my Form:

[image: Dropdown and Textfield on my Form]

When I save the post with chosen category I will see after submit the properties input fields.  This is working.

It is necessary but not nice. Ok, I need a solution with ajax. Without Symfony no problem but with a big^^

I Google this and see, I need a CRUD Controller and a Event in my Form TypeClass.

My TypeClass:

```
class PropertiesType extends AbstractType
{

    public $em;

    private $session;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em,Session $session)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->session = $session;

    }

    protected function generateFormInputs(FormEvent $event){

        $form = null;

        if(!is_array($event->getData()) && ($event->getData() === null || !$event->getData()->getCategory())){
            return false;
        }

        if(!is_array($event->getData())){
            $furniture = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
        }else{
            $pp = $this->em->getRepository('ProductBundle:Furniture')->findOneBy(array('id' => $event->getData()['furniture_id']));
            $pp->setCategory($this->em->getRepository('ProductBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array('id' => $event->getData()['category_id'])));
            $event->setData($pp);
            $furniture = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
        }


        if($furniture !== null){

            foreach($furniture->getCategory()->getProperties() as $val){

                $repo = $this->em->getRepository('ProductBundle:FurnitureProperties')->findOneBy(array('furniture' => $furniture->getId(), 'property' => $val->getId()));

                if($repo === null){
                    $repo = new FurnitureProperties();
                    $repo->addProperty($val);
                    $repo->addFurniture($furniture);
                    $repo->setPropertyId($val->getId());
                    $repo->setCurrentLocale($this->session->get('_locale'));
                }

                $form->add('properties_'.$val->getId(), 'text', array(
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'label' => $val->getName(),
                    'data' => $repo,
                    'required' => false
                ));
            }

        }
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {

            if($event->getData() !== null){

                foreach($event->getData() as $key => $val){
                    $obj = '';
                    $obj = $event->getForm()->get($key)->getData();

                    if($val !== ''){
                        $obj->setText($val);


                        $this->em->persist($obj);
                        $obj->mergeNewTranslations();
                        $this->em->flush();
                    }else{
                        $this->em->remove($obj);
                        $this->em->flush();
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $this->generateFormInputs($event);
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ProductBundle\Entity\Furniture',
            'empty_data' => new FurnitureProperties(),
        ));
    }

}
```

My CRUD Controller:

```
<?php

namespace ProductBundle\Controller;

use ProductBundle\Form\Type\PropertiesType;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class FurnitureCRUDController extends Controller
{
    public function ajaxAction($furniture_id, $category_id, Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(PropertiesType::class, array(
            'furniture_id' => $furniture_id,
            'category_id' => $category_id
        ));



        $form->handleRequest($request);


        return $this->render('form/fields.html.twig',
            array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            )
        );


    }
}
```

My twig template:

```
{% block properties_widget %}

    {% if id is defined %}
        {% set token = id|split('_')[0] %}

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#{{ token }}'+'_category').change(function(){

                    var current_element = this;

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url : '/admin/product/furniture/ajax/{{ form.vars.value.id }}/'+jQuery(current_element).val()+'?uniqid={{ token }}',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: $("form").serialize(),
                        success: function(html) {
                            jQuery('.category_replacement').html(html);

                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

    {% endif %}


    <div class="category_replacement">
        {% for fields in form.children %}

            {% set attr = fields.vars %}

            <div id="sonata-ba-field-container-{{ attr.id }}" class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ attr.id }}" class="control-label {{ attr.required == true ? 'required' : '' }}">{{ attr.label }}</label>

                <div class="sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-standard-natural">
                    <input class="form-control" name="{{ attr.full_name }}" id="{{ attr.id }}" value="{{ attr.value }}" {{ attr.required == true ? 'required="required"' : '' }}>
                </div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

If I do it all. I get this result (Browser).

```
<div class="category_replacement">

    <div id="sonata-ba-field-container-properties_properties_1" class="form-group">
        <label for="properties_properties_1" class="control-label ">höhe</label>

        <div class="sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-standard-natural">
            <input class="form-control" name="properties[properties_1]" id="properties_properties_1" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sonata-ba-field-container-properties__token" class="form-group">
        <label for="properties__token" class="control-label "></label>

        <div class="sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-standard-natural">
            <input class="form-control" name="properties[_token]" id="properties__token" value="AhNHvQrq_8f6ObAOTB1MmbX7Nv_FBmFsgQe3z_sH7qg">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My Original but looks so (Browser):

```
<div class="category_replacement">

    <div id="sonata-ba-field-container-s594d9b1861e8e_furniture_properties_1" class="form-group">
        <label for="s594d9b1861e8e_furniture_properties_1" class="control-label ">height</label>

        <div class="sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-standard-natural">
            <input class="form-control" name="s594d9b1861e8e[furniture][properties_1]" id="s594d9b1861e8e_furniture_properties_1" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

What is the problem? The Ajax request doesn't have a unique id? I think, no problem I will change this with JavaScript.

But after submit the Form. Symfony doesn't know my Input Field/s. Why?

When I use the Form without this Ajax Solution. I can add Entities to the Form and work with them after submit. But when i use the ajax solution, i can not work with the entities, I think this is bad.

The only option would be to add the Property ID to the name attributes on the input fields and load this from the db.

If it helps. My Composer Requirements:

```
"php": ">=5.5.9",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.2",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
"knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "^1.4",
"nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.20",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.19.0",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
"sonata-project/google-authenticator": "^2.0",
"sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.5",
"sonata-project/translation-bundle": "^2.1",
"sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
"symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
"symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
"twig/twig": "1.34.3"
```

And yes I know. The solution with the ID is not the best:

```
'properties_'.$val->getId()
```

But this is a other question :)

Comment: Is none here who can help me?
the only thing was i trying to do is to add textfields to a form (with ajax) and save to db.

Comment: Did you resolved this? If yes, kindly post the answer. So that it may help others like me. Thanks!